# Pull Foursquare City and State Location

Tags: javascript, dom, foursquare

I have a landing page site and I would like to pull my latest checkin location.

EX:
Currently in San Francisco, CA

What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Foursquare provided RSS Feed and use jQuery to parse the feed. Foursquare provides the feeds: https://foursquare.com/feeds/ and can use jQuery.ajax() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/